# Compile element to specific location without any #localvariable

Tags: angular, dynamic, components, local-variables

Is there any way to add dynamic element in to specific location without `#localvariable` (`<input type='button' #localvariable (click)='doSomething()'>`).

For example, given:

```
<td></td>
```

After compiling:

```
<td><input type='button' (click)='doSomething()'></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ComponentFactory.create` allows to pass a selector or node as target parameter:

```ts
constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private injector: Injector) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  let factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyDynamicComponent);
  let compRef = factory.create(injector, [], '#idOfTarget'); 
}
```

See also https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactory#create

Comment: using 'ComponentFactory.create' how can we pass data into component. and my second question Is it possible to pass element as a string instead of component.

Comment: `compRef.instance.someField = 'foo';` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468 also shows how to do it.